# GWT Canvas - How do I get the mouse location on the Canvas during a KeyPress event?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a GWT application with a Canvas. I added several event handlers to the canvas, including a KeyPressedHandler.

When the user presses a key and the KeyPressEvent is fired, I want to find out the mouse's location within the Canvas (similar to that provided by MouseEvent.getX(), MouseEvent.getY(). However, neither KeyPressEvent nor NativeEvent provide this information as far as I can tell. How can I obtain it?

Thanks!

Comment: Our current solution is to keep track of the last mouse position using the MouseMoveHandler. It works pretty well. Someone here proposed this but his answer vanished so I can't accept it :\ .

Answer (score 1):

A `MouseMoveHandler` will help, but this won't work until the user actually moves the mouse...